# fullcalendar startParam format v3.0.1

Tags: json, fullcalendar

with fullcalendar v3.0.1 I try to set initial date range with this setting:

```
startParam: '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
```

but, if I go back into the past with arrows button, I can back to 2016 and previous years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think that startParam restricts when the calendar can go back to? It's a parameter passed to the server when new events are fetched which tells the server the start date from which events should be returned in the current request - generally it will correspond to the start date of the current view in the calendar. And if you look at the docs for this property: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/, it mentions nothing about what you describe. I don't understand why you thought this would work.

If, for some reason, you want to stop users going back in time before a certain date, there is no currently official supported way to do this. This issue log: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/429 suggests that support may arrive in a future version, but at present you will need to work around it.

To be honest though I'm not sure why you really would need to do this. If you want to prevent users seeing any events before a particular date, the simplest way would be not to provide any event data to the calendar which is before that date - then if the user moves to those earlier dates, the calendar would simply be blank.

If you really feel you need to do this though, the only way I can think of would be to handle the viewRender event, and if the first day displayed in the view is on or before your minimum date, disable the "previous" button, or something.

Comment: Ok, I try to deny with some work around. Any suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: try my suggestion with the viewRender event and pre-emptively disabling the "previous" button. Remember to re-enable it again if the dates are ok. The range you test for might depend on the view (because a different number of days is shown in each view)